# How can I programmatically with c++ force Windows chkdsk to show bad sectors?

Tags: c++, windows, disk, sector

I'm testing a tool that parses chkdsk errors and does stuff with the info found. The only part I haven't been able to test yet is the report of bad sectors on the drive. How can I programmatically force Windows chkdsk to report that it has found bad sectors? Is this possible to do with c++?

I found code for unix but it doesn't compile in Visual Studio 2008 and I've been told it doesn't work like I want it to either. http://anshulkatta.blogspot.com/2011/12/create-bad-sectors-on-hard-disk.html

Is there a programmatic trick I can do to simulate or force a bad sector on a drive? I believe there is malware out there that already does this, or it might just be referring to the boot sector which isn't really what I'm looking for here.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why aren't you testing your parser just based on the text output of chkdsk, without involving a 'real' chkdsk call at all?

Comment: I was considering that and we might have to settle for something of that sort. I was hoping to do a black box test of this and see if there were possible strangenesses of the output ... which microsoft loves. Also, I am curious to see if chkdsk finishes properly when there are bad sectors it is reading. I might have to handle those error situations as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are loads of samples for various chkdsk error reports to be found on the internet. As for reacting on chkdsk behavior correctly, provide a mock (program) that just ouputs the error report for a particular test case, and simulates chdsk's (expected) behavior.

Comment: If all else fails, taking a giant magnet and/or a hammer to a hard drive might help. :)

Comment: Mocking works IF I know all the possible outputs. I want to test on a ton of different hard drives with actual data to get as many outputs as possible.

Comment: Also we are making a call to chkdsk through a pipe and parsing the data from there. A code change would have to be made in order to accommodate my test which I want to avoid because I'm not the developer, only the tester. I don't want to burden the already swamped developer with my menial testing tasks that may seem unnecessary. Also, we have noticed that the output seen through the pipe is different sometimes than what you would see in the command window, strange I know but they must see that you are using a different output source and modify the output for that. Kind of lame if you ask me.

Comment: I want to avoid ruining these drives completely as well LOL thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I'm not sure why people LOVE just putting comments on my question rather than attempt to post an answer as a real answer. This has happened with last 3 questions I've asked ... it's very discouraging.

Comment: @BrianTHannan _'I'm not sure why people LOVE just putting comments on my question ...'_ As for me, because I could give no answer to your original question, but still have some advice for you. BTW, I don't think it should be necessary to change the code to provide a chkdsk mocking program. If the developer used a hardcoded path, you can still replace chkdsk.exe with your mock there.

Comment: @BrianTHannan ... and try to address people explicitly when answering comments (use the @ in beginning of your comment) ...

Comment: @g-makulik Thanks for the advice. I will try replacing chkdsk.exe to see what happens.

Comment: @g-makulik turns out it is very difficult to replace chkdsk.exe on XP because looks like Winlogon.exe automatically replaces the file if you muck with it ... probably a CRC check. On Win764 you have to have a 64-bit mock created which my Visual Studio environment currently doesn't do so couldn't really test it but the idea seems solid if I get around these issues. Thanks Man!